# scraper only returning results for first 2 inputs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to build a scrape tool that imports a csv file, then attaches each row from the csv to a url, then scrapes that url for a specific field. So far the tool adds all the urls and scrapes for the data, but it only returns the data for the first 2 and just displays the url for the rest:

```
import urllib
import re
import requests
from numpy import genfromtxt
from time import sleep

my_data = genfromtxt('ASINS.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

for ASIN in my_data[:20]:
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/" + ASIN[1:11]
    sleep(1.5)
    website_html = requests.get(url).text
    print len(website_html)
    print url

    ranks = re.findall(r'#.\sin\s.*', website_html)
    for rank in ranks:
        print rank
```

The output only returns the scrape for the first, example below:

```
344781
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DPE9EQO
#1 in Beauty (<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/beauty">See Top 100 in     Beauty</a>)
1378
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CD0H1ZC
327515
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GP184WO
1378
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CAZAU62
1378
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KCFAZTE
1378
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C7DYBX0
3
```

and a snip from the csv:

```
B00DPE9EQO  
B00CD0H1ZC  
B00GP184WO  
B00CAZAU62  
B00KCFAZTE  
B00C7DYBX0  
B00IS8Y0HK  
B00CKFL93K  
B00DDT116M  
B00GYF65TK  
B00JV8L5N8
```

Can anyone give me any input on why it might be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things that helped me to scrape the data you requested:

- use [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) that helps to maintain cookies
- specify `User-Agent` header
- use an HTML Parser (chose [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) to extract the `Best Sellers Ranks`

Complete code:

```
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import genfromtxt
import requests


my_data = genfromtxt('ASINS.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

# initialize a session
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36'}

for ASIN in my_data[:20]:
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/" + ASIN[1:11]
    sleep(1.5)

    response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    print url
    # get best seller rankings
    for rank in soup.select('ul.zg_hrsr li.zg_hrsr_item'):
        print rank.text
    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DPE9EQO

#1
in Health & Personal Care > Vitamins & Dietary Supplements > Vitamins > Vitamin C > C-Complex


#1
in Beauty > Skin Care > Face > Creams & Moisturizers > Fluids & Lotions > Fluids


#1
in Beauty > Skin Care > Face > Oils & Serums

----
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CD0H1ZC

#1
in Pet Supplies > Dogs > Grooming > Shedding Tools


#1
in Pet Supplies > Cats > Grooming > Shedding Tools

----
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GP184WO

#1
in Health & Personal Care > Health Care > Sleep & Snoring > Sleeping Masks

----
...
```

Comment: Wow this works beautifully! If i just wanted to return the first category and not the sub categories how would I change that part?

Comment: @amazingacademy let me ask you what do you mean by the first category. For example, for [this product](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DPE9EQO), what is your desired output? Thank you.

Comment: for example, a product will be #1 in Health & Personal Care > Vitamins & Dietary Supplement, and #3 in Health & Personal Care. It lists this on the amazon product page if it is more than one. I want to return just the first one.

Comment: so for that product, just returns  #1 in Health & Personal Care > Vitamins & Dietary Supplements > Vitamins > Vitamin C > C-Complex

Comment: @amazingacademy well, one option would be to put `break` after the `print rank.text` line. Another, to use `find()` instead of `select()`: `print soup.find('li', class_='zg_hrsr_item').text`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, all those results that are the same small size, 1378 bytes long, are probably "404 Not Found" pages of some kind. I'd try doing one test run with `if len(website_html) == 1378: print website_html` and seeing what gets output. If it turns out you're getting a 404 Not Found, or some other error like "You're retrieving pages too fast and we think you're a bot, so we won't give you that page", then you'll know how to fix your code (e.g., increase that `sleep()` time in the latter case).

Second, your regular expression will only work if there's exactly one character after the #. If something is ranked 10th or lower (e.g. a numerically-greater rank number), your regex will fail. Try `#\d+` instead of `#.` and see if that helps.

... Ah. While I was writing this, someone else gave a better answer. Good. I'll still post this, because the suggestions I made aren't duplicated, and they might help too.

Comment: Using `BeautifulSoup` is much better than regular expressions. Ignore my "how to fix your regex" suggestion and go with alecxe's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm pretty new to python but i'm looking into BeautifulSoup and Scrapy right now